# How to read and process an Excel spreadsheet in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, excel, spreadsheet

I need to read line-by-line through an Excel spreadsheet which is stored locally on my computer and create HTML elements for each line. Ideally this would change the page if the original Excel document is changed.

I'm using vanilla Javascript. What library / other method should I use to read the spreadsheet?

Comment: I hope you mean node.js by vanilla JS, If so you might find success with [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs).

Comment: @lejlun Unfortunately, I don't. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.js"></script>
var exportExcelToJson = function() {

  this.parseExcel = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
      });

      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        var xlObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        var json_object = JSON.stringify(xlObject);
        console.log(json_object);

      })

    };

    reader.onerror = function(sendErr) {
      console.log(sendErr);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };
};
</script>


It's a function converts the Excel sheet type XLSX data to JSON and you can add promise to the function.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm trying this now.

Comment: what should I parse to parseExcel() for "file"? a path to the spreadsheet?

Comment: you add a file excel then code check each sheet return to a json_object.

Comment: would this be a valid object to pass the function? 

var lexicon = new File(["lexicon"], "../lexicon.xlsx", {
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
});

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try it.